# How do i format the ouput of a list of list into a textfile properly?

Tags: python, formatting, output

I am really new to python and now I am struggeling with some problems while working on a student project. Basically I try to read data from a text file which is formatted in columns. I store the data in a list of list and sort and manipulate the data and write them into a file again. My problem is to align the written data in proper columns. I found some approaches like

> "%i, %f, %e" % (1000, 1000, 1000)

but I don't know how many columns there will be. So I wonder if there is a way to set all columns to a fixed width.

This is how the input data looks like:

```
2     232.248E-09         74.6825             2.5         5.00008         499.482
5             10.         74.6825             2.5        -16.4304           -12.3
```

This is how I store the data in a list of list:

```
  filename = getInput('MyPath', workdir)
  lines = []
  f = open(filename, 'r')
    while 1:
        line = f.readline()
        if line == '':
            break
        splitted = line.split()
        lines.append(splitted)            
    f.close()
```

To write the data I first put all the row elements of the list of list into one string with a free fixed space between the elements. But instead i need a fixed total space including the element. But also I don't know the number of columns in the file.

```
for k in xrange(len(lines)):
    stringlist=""
    for i in lines[k]:
        stringlist = stringlist+str(i)+'        '
    lines[k] = stringlist+'\n'

    f = open(workdir2, 'w')
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        f.write(lines[i])
    f.close()
```

This code works basically, but sadly the output isn't formatted properly.

Thank you very much in advance for any help on this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely right about begin able to format widths as you have above using string formatting. But as you correctly point out, the tricky bit is doing this for a variable sized output list. Instead, you could use the join() function:

```
output = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',]

# format each column (len(a)) with a width of 10 spaces
width = [10]*len(a)

# write it out, using the join() function
with open('output_example', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join('%*s' % i for i in zip(width, output)))
```

will write out:

```
'         a         b         c         d         e'
```

As you can see, the length of the format array `width` is determined by the length of the output, `len(a)`. This is flexible enough that you can generate it on the fly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for the fast answer! With your help I managed to write a little function which now does exactly what I need:

    def WriteOutput(matrix):
        workdir2 = os.getcwd() + '/abaqusc.rpt'
        # format each column (len(a)) with a width of 10 spaces
        width = [20]*len(matrix[0])
        with open(workdir2, 'w') as f:
            for j in xrange(len(matrix)):
                f.write(''.join('%*s' % i for i in zip(width, matrix[j]))+'\n')

Answer (score 0):

String formatting might be the way to go:

```
>>> print("%10s%9s" % ("test1", "test2"))
     test1    test2
```

Though you might want to first create strings from those numbers and then format them as I showed above.

I cannot fully comprehend your *writing* code, but try working on it somehow like that:

```
from itertools import enumerate

with open(workdir2, 'w') as datei:
    for key, item in enumerate(zeilen):
        line = "%4i %6.6" % key, item
        datei.write(item)
```